# Excel Macro listing all files within the contained directory and hyperlinking them

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a macro already however i need it to also hyperlink the files in column U along with the file list in column A.

Here is my code right now, how can i add the hyperlinking feature?
i don't mind if I have to add another module either.

```
Sub ListFilesAndSubfolders()

  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim rsFSO As Object
  Dim baseFolder As Object
  Dim file As Object
  Dim folder As Object
  Dim row As Integer
  Dim name As String

  'Get the current folder
  Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set baseFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
  Set FSO = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
  row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
  Set rsFSO = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsFSO.Fields
    .Append "Name", 200, 200
    .Append "Type", 200, 200
  End With
  rsFSO.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree baseFolder, baseFolder, rsFSO
  Set baseFolder = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsFSO.Sort = "Type ASC, Name ASC "
  rsFSO.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
  While Not rsFSO.EOF
    name = rsFSO("Name").Value
    If (name <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      Cells(row, 1).Formula = name
      row = row + 1
    End If
    rsFSO.MoveNext
  Wend

  'Close the recordset
  rsFSO.Close
  Set rsFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each file In node.Files

    Dim name As String
    name = Mid(file.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Name") = name
    rs("Type") = "FILE"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
  For Each folder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, folder, rs
  Next

End Sub
```

prompt replies would be very welcome as my project deadline is only a few weeks off.

thank you!

Comment: Look at [`Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx). And are you using a recordset as an array replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the file.Path to your record set and then when you want to link them in your loop try something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(row, 1), Address:=file.Path, TextToDisplay:=name
```

---

***Edit***

After rs.AddNew add this line:

```
rs("Path") = file.Path
```

Add one more append:

```
With rsFSO.Fields
  .Append "Path", 200, 200
  .Append "Name", 200, 200
  .Append "Type", 200, 200
End With
```

Now change this part of your code like this:

```
  While Not rsFSO.EOF
    name = rsFSO("Name").Value
    path = rsFSO("Path").Value
    If (name <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(row, 1), Address:=path, TextToDisplay:=name
      row = row + 1
    End If
    rsFSO.MoveNext
  Wend
```

You might have to add the definition at the top of your code like this:

```
dim path as string
```

Comment: where would I put this code in the previous code, sorry very new to VB.

Comment: See my edit above, you'll have to change a few different parts.  Let me know what errors you get and what lines they are from.

Comment: did all that you said and i got runtime "3265"
item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

highlights the rs("Path") = file.Path after the rs.addnew

Comment: See my last edit I forgot to add this: .Append "Path", 200, 200