# Directory List hyperlink macro needs to move to another column

Tags: excel, vba

So earlier today I got my code fixed to hyperlink, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to put the list in Column U instead of column A.

```
Sub hyperlinker()

  Dim MOG As Object
  Dim rsMOG As Object
  Dim PrimeF As Object
  Dim Bit As Object
  Dim Foder As Object 
  Dim Linger As Integer
  Dim Enigma As String
  Dim Way As String


  'Get the current folder
  Set MOG = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set PrimeF = MOG.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
  Set MOG = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
   Linger = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
   Set rsMOG = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsMOG.Fields
    .Append "Way", 200, 200
    .Append "Enigma", 200, 200
    .Append "Bit", 200, 200
  End With
  rsMOG.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree PrimeF, PrimeF, rsMOG
  Set PrimeF = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsMOG.Sort = "Bit ASC, Enigma ASC "
  rsMOG.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
  While Not rsMOG.EOF
    Enigma = rsMOG("Enigma").value
    Way = rsMOG("Way").value
    If (Enigma <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Linger, 1), Address:=Way, TextToDisplay:=Enigma
      Linger = Linger + 1
    End If
    rsMOG.MoveNext
  Wend

  'Close the recordset
  rsMOG.Close
  Set rsMOG = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each Bit In node.Files

    Dim Enigma As String
    Enigma = Mid(Bit.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Way") = Way
    rs("Enigma") = Enigma
    rs("Bit") = "Bit"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
  For Each Foder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, Foder, rs
  Next

End Sub
```

pardon the random words in the index, I had to change them to odd names due to the use of the usual words in another macro.

basically,

```
dim linger as integer
```

and

```
'Get the row at which to insert
  Linger = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1
```

give me column A no mater what I put in there, can someone help me to get this hyperlink list to column U?

Comment: here is the link to the last answer i got in fixing my macro to hyperlink the directory list.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148596/excel-macro-listing-all-files-within-the-contained-directory-and-hyperlinking-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `U` holds an index of `21`.

So replace

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Linger, 1), Address:=Way, TextToDisplay:=Enigma
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Linger, 21), Address:=Way, TextToDisplay:=Enigma
```

and you should be able to get your hyperlinks in column `U`

---

See when using `Cells` object the first parameter is the row number, and the second is the column number.

So, `Cells(1,1)` corresponds to `A1` which is the same as `Range("A1")`

`Cells(linger,21)` will be whatever the value of *`linger`* is in column `U`

or

`Range("U" & linger)` will be an alternative

Comment: thank you so much for your help, works like a charm and now I'm all prepared for tomorrow =P good night